# Simultaneous actions with the -te form

Tags: grammar, syntax

In English you can use conjunction to express two simultaneous actions:

> I was standing in front of an audience and presenting a new technology.

Or simply juxtapose two participles where one modifies the other:

> I was standing in front of an audience, presenting a new technology.

Am I correct to suppose that in Japanese you would use something like 立って、出していました (i.e. juxtaposed -te form verbs) for both variants?

Comment: 立って出していました means ---- well, I don't think I'm allowed to say that here....

Comment: how about you go with something like 立って、食べていました instead? :)

Comment: @TokyoNagoya スケベ!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but there are multiple ways to say it. Just off the top of my head, I can think of at least these:

- 聴衆の前に立ち、新製品の発表を行った
- 聴衆の前に立って、新製品の発表を行った
- 聴衆の前に立ちつつ、新製品の発表を行った
- 聴衆の前に立ちながら、新製品の発表を行った

Some of them has subtle nuances that others don't have, but I think all of them are more or less interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks! Which one of them is closest to an English conjunction with "and"?